# clickhouse как вернуть название месяца текстом

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Есть запрос, он возвращает мне месяц как число(1,2,3...) как переписать запрос чтобы месяц возвращался в виде текста (Январь,Февраль,Март...) :
'''

```
with t1 as(
        select count(status) as test1,
               toMonth(time) as "date"
        from test
        group by "date"
),
t2 as (
        select count(status) as test2,
               toMonth(time) as "date"
        from test
        where status = 1
        group by "date"
)
select t1."date",
       (t2.test2 / t1.test1) * 100
from t1
inner join t2 on t1."date" = t2."date"
order by "date"
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,t1."date")
```

или

```
    SELECT COUNT(status) as test1,
           DATENAME(time) as "date"
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. но ещё нужно учесть что clickhouse регистрозависимый.
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,t1."date") так не работает
SELECT DATENAME(month ,t1."date") а так работает

Comment: @RinNohara Спасибо, исправил. Привык писать функции, типы и подобные вещи в большом регистре